# Request stack of items for crafting recipe?

Tags: minecraft-forge

Is there a way to require a stack of items in a crafting recipe? I tried something like this:

```
GameRegistry.addRecipe(new ItemStack(myCustomItemHere), "iii", "iii", "iii", 'i', new ItemStack(requiredItemHere, 64));
```

I would like a similar example to this where I require a full (64) stack of `requiredItemHere`, using minecraft **1.7.10** with forge **10.13.4.1448**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to implement IRecipe on a class and then register it via `GameRegistry.addRecipe(IRecipe recipe)`. That'll let you examine the entire crafting grid and all itemstacks in it.

Comment: That's what I ended up doing. I'll accept anyway, since it was the correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

Not as far as I know with the default crafting manager of minecraft.

You could always implement your own crafting manager code where people can put in items according to your spec. You only have to craft your own GUI's for that and your own "crafting tables" to make this possible. For example thaumcraft's arcane workbench.

You can always listen to the crafting event and update according to that event, but that event is fired after the crafting and can't stop the crafting itself if not meeting your requirements.

Comment: Is there a way to do this with a custom manager in the vanilla table? (I've seen similar things with other mods, but not item stacking).

Comment: no, i've tried this to, but it only takes one item. otherwise the shiftclick code breaks. The only way you can enforce multiple items is by having it in multiple slots. Creating your own tileentity with inventory, event managers and recipe manager that defaults back to vanilla crafting recipes might be the best way for you to go.

Comment: I figured out that I can use an event handler to detect the number of items in a crafting slot and deplete them as necessary. If there aren't enough items, I just change the damage value and add a tooltip that says the item is worthless. The damage value makes the item unusable in other crafting recipes.

Comment: The only issue is that when the user shift-clicks the item, the damage value isn't applied. This allows it to stack with the wrong items. Is there a way to disable the shift-click.

Comment: As well, is there a way to manually update the crafting output? I modified my design to modify the damage value of one of the crafting components, but the crafting output doesn't update properly.